# python unittest mock a nested function

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

i have a function `x` in `main.applications.handlers` package

```
from main.config import get_db

def x(company_name):
        db = get_db('my_db')
        apps = []
        for x in company_db.applications.find():
            print(x)
            apps.append(x)
        return apps
```

now i want to write unittest for this method .

```
from unittest.mock import Mock,patch, MagicMock

@mock.patch('main.applications.handlers.get_db')
def test_show_applications_handler(self, mocked_db):
    mocked_db.applications.find  = MagicMock(return_value=[1,2,3])
    apps = x('test_company') # apps should have [1,2,3] but its []
    print(apps)
```

but `company_db.applications.find()` inside `main.applications.handlers` is not returning anything .it should return `[1,2,3]`
what could be wrong with this code?

Comment: what do you get if you replace the x in `apps = x('test_company')` with `find`?

Comment: @Nick find is not defined error

Comment: @Nick i get `<MagicMock name='get_db().applications.find()' id='140565332675720'>` when i do `print (company_db.applications.find())` inside `x`

Comment: i also tried this `mocked_db.return_value.applications.return_value.find.return_value = [1,2,3]` but same result

Comment: Is `company_db` a typo? I can't see where that is defined. Presumably it should be `db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `company_db` is a typo and should be `db`, then to mock the return value of `find()`, you would do:

```
mocked_db.return_value.applications.find = MagicMock(return_value=[1,2,3])
```

`mocked_db` requires a `return_value` because `get_db` is called with the database name.

You could also drop the `MagicMock` and set the `return_value` of `find` directly:

```
mocked_db.return_value.applications.find.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @WillKeeping it worked when i used `mocked_db().return_value.applications.find = MagicMock(return_value=[1,2,3])` but not with `mocked_db.return_value.applications.find = MagicMock(return_value=[1,2,3])
`